# Scala: How to filter out maps with a common key value from a list of maps

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, filter

I have a List of Map:

```
val input = List( Map("id" -> "abc", "val" -> 100), 
                  Map("id" -> "abc", "val" -> 109), 
                  Map("id" -> "bca", "val" -> 115), 
                  Map("id" -> "acb", "val" -> 100), 
                  Map("id" -> "cba", "val" -> 105),
                  Map("id" -> "cba", "val" -> 110), 
                  Map("id" -> "cba", "val" -> 116) )
```

From which I need to filter out all the maps that share a common value for key "id".  In other words, I have to only keep maps for which the value of key id is unique.

```
val output = List( Map("id" -> "bca", "val" -> 115), 
                   Map("id" -> "acb", "val" -> 100) )
```

Answer (score 8):

Use grouping

`input.groupBy(x => x("id")).filter(y => y._2.size == 1).map(_._2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, with a flatMap instead of a map, it gives exactly what I want.